# Chrome background color suddenly changed to black

Tags: google-chrome

I'm not talking about a dark theme setting on Chrome that didn't change anything for this issue even if I changed it back and forth, but Chrome suddenly changed its background color from white to black for some web pages which don't set any background color, it seems.

Please take a look at these two pictures. They are the same web pages but the former one is that normally I opened it and the latter one is opened with incognito mode.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

===EDIT===
I relaunched chrome, but didn't work.
Also restarted my PC, but didn't work either.

[image]

[image]

===EDIT2===
Disabling this setting helped me! Thank you very much everyone and @leeharvey1 !

```
chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to be an issue in Chrome that affects multiple users. You can try it in another browser or use incognito mode for the time being.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the browser cache? Note: There is [a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1706745/what-could-be-causing-this-on-multiple-sites) about chrome displaying some elements dark without changing any settings

Comment: @LPChip If using incognito solves the problem, it most likey has to do something with saved website data.

Comment: Try disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome, and visit these experimental Chrome settings: `chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark` and `chrome://flags/#color-provider-redirection-for-theme-provider`

Comment: @leeharvey1 As I edited the question, disabling `chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark` worked for me. Can you post it as an answer? I'll make it an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Chrome **Experiments** page, change the `chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark` setting from `Default` to `Disabled`.

Comment: The only answer that worked. Thank you so much!