# What could be causing this on multiple sites?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, user-interface

I have added no new chrome themes or extensions, and I have not changed my dark mode settings.

I just woke up this morning, and some websites have graphical glitches like the one above and uncharacteristically dark website backgrounds.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an English translation?

Comment: It's the amazon dropdown.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Has perhaps the computer installed some updates (check *Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update > View update history*).

Comment: Have you tried to delete your browser cache?

Comment: @flyinggoatman - That isn't clear by your non-English screenshot.  Have you tried restarting Chrome?

Comment: Over the last couple hours, Chrome has been doing the same thing to me on some sites. Black text boxes with black text, white text on a light grey background (arstechnica.com) etc. odd.

Comment: Many of my colleagues have reported this issue today, where chrome is inverting colors for some fonts.